# SQL - Ordering table with subquery for select

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by

I am trying to do ordering on query with subquery for a `name` from `uuid`. Let's have those two tables in MySQL:

bans:

| id | uuid | time | reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c6b8eade-7db9-345b-b838-8f8361552cf5 | 1642369382 | Test |
| 2 | 0138c279-c5fa-3acd-adaa-8edb7b4569d8 | 1642384565 | Spam |
| 3 | 3c01262c-a3c3-3133-ba43-92a9ded01c27 | 1631876477 | Hax |

users:

| id | uuid | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | c6b8eade-7db9-345b-b838-8f8361552cf5 | John |
| 100 | 0138c279-c5fa-3acd-adaa-8edb7b4569d8 | Mike |
| 35 | 3c01262c-a3c3-3133-ba43-92a9ded01c27 | Norman |

With this query, I can select whole `ban` record + fetch user's `name` from `users` table:

```sql
SELECT
    bans.*,
    (SELECT users.name FROM users WHERE users.uuid = bans.uuid) as name
FROM bans
ORDER BY :column;
```

But I cannot order by `name`. How to change this query so I can do ordering by `users.name`? I tried to wrap my SQL select into another select, but it does not work and I am unable to resolve it :D

Comment: You cannot make a column or table name a parameter

Comment: And you need a JOIN and not a subquery for that

Comment: It is just placeholder. I copied it from my PHP PDO query

Comment: Yes, but you CANNOT make a column name a PARAMETER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a JOIN query if I ever saw one.

You cannot pass a table or column name as a parameter in either PDO or MYSQLI. The database cannot compile and optimise code with unknown columns or tables in it

```
SELECT b.*, u.name
FROM bans b
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.uuid = b.uuid
ORDER BY u.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this

```
select a.id, a.uuid, a.time, a.reason, b.name from bans a
left join users b
on a.uuid = b.uuid
order by b.name;
```

Comment: Its always a good idea to make your alias's have at least something to do with the thing you are aliasing